# jquery timed function not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a javascript function which should call itself every 3 seconds for the game page of a poker website. It only calls itself once

heres the php

```
if(isset($_GET['displayGame']))   //Check if submitted
{
  $thisPokergame = new pokerGame();
  $thisPokergame->read($_GET['gameid']);

  $thisPlayer->read($_GET['userid']);

  // $thisPokergame->State['currentUser'] = $thisPokergame->State['privatePlayerData'][$_GET['userid']];

  // unset($thisPokergame->State['privatePlayerData']);
  // $thisPokergame->State['players'].length();
  // $thisPokergame->State = array('1'=>'test');
  echo json_encode($thisPokergame->State);
  return;
}
```

this is the javascript

```
function refreshGamepage()
{
  console.log("gameid:"+$("#gameid").val());
  console.log("userid:"+$("#userid").val());
  console.log("refresh");

  $.getJSON( "playGame.php", {displayGame:"true",gameid:$("#gameid").val(),userid:$("#userid").val()}, function( data ) {
  console.log("got checkGameState response: "+data['BuyIn']);
  $( "#myContent" ).empty();
  if(data['Status'] === "pending" )
  {
    $( "#myContent" ).append('<p>game is pending</p>');
  }
  else if (data['Status'] === "inProgress")
  {
    $( "#myContent" ).append('<p>game is in progress</p>');
    $( "#myContent" ).append('<p>hand is</p>');
    $( "#myContent" ).append('<p>pot is </p>');
    $( "#myContent" ).append('<p>stack is </p>');
  }
  else if (data['Status'] === "finalized")
  {
    $( "#myContent" ).append('<p>game is over</p>');
  }
  else
  {
    $( "#myContent" ).append('<p>invalid game state</p>');
  }

  setTimeout("refreshGamepage()",3000);
  });
}
```

and this is is in the playGame page to run the function when the page loads

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        console.log("running script");
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            console.log("running ready");
            refreshGamepage();
        });
</script>
```

the console logs stop just before the "got gamestate repsonse in the javascript so it would lead me to believe there is an error in the php response

Comment: Are you aware of the developer tools in Chrome/Firefox? They let you see exactly what http requests were made. They also let you debug your code by placing breakpoints on a functional line of code. Look it up, it'll save you the trouble of adding console.log all of the time. ([See here for chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging)

Comment: Run the php script from the browser to test it as `xxx.com/filename.php?displayGame&gameid=2&id=22` and you should see the output on the browser. Use a valid parameters of course

Comment: running script,     
 running ready,   
 gameid:60,    
 userid:2,   
refresh

Comment: thats the output on the browser, from the logs

Comment: Well then there is code you are not showing us, as I dont see where those texts are being generated in what you are currently showing us. Unless they are coming from the `$thisPokergame` class in which case that will be confusing the javascript as it will be receiving those messages when you run it normally from the AJAX code

Comment: the first two are generated in the script at the very bottom and the last three are generated at the beginning of the refreshGampage() javascript function